# adding a click event to a key event

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

How can I make the button appear pressed regardless of how I trigger the event? (either with the keydown event or the click event). I thought about adding "click()" to the keydown event, but it doesn´t work

Comment: What exactly do you mean by it is not working? Is the function getting executed? Are you getting any error messages on console? Please explain a little but more so we can help you :)

Comment: so when you click the button the audio plays and when you hit enter it plays as well?

Comment: or does it not do that yet?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! It`s working: a click event triggers the audio, and a key event also triggers the audio. What I want is for the key event to also make the button look pressed!

Comment: okay so make your own css for and attach it to the key that is playing and then remove it when it finishes playing

Comment: There is no way to really do that, you can set focus to it.... or do custom css

Comment: Ah. Thank you for the insight. I thought I could just do a click event trigger at the same time the keydown happens.

Comment: How could I add the focus or the css class after the key event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way through javascript to trigger the UserAgent styles and make a button look "pressed". You will probably need to use a css solution, which you can style to look like the default button if you really wanted.

That means you would need to track the down and up events of the buttons so you can control what state the button is in. I have an example of that below.

```js
const drumpad = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.drum-pad'));
    const displaytext = document.querySelector('#displaytext');

    const texts = ["Heater 1", "Heater 2", "Heater 3", "Heater 4", "Heater 6", "Open HH", "Kick N Hat", "Kick", "Closed HH"]; 
    const keycodes = [81, 87, 69, 65, 83, 68, 90, 88, 67];

    function downhandler(e) { 
      const index = e.type === 'keydown'?keycodes.indexOf(e.keyCode):drumpad.indexOf(this); 
      const target = drumpad[index]; 
      if (!target) return; 
      const audio = target.childNodes[0]; 
      audio.play(); 
      displaytext.textContent = texts[index]; 
      if(e.type === "mousedown"){
        //if we're a button (click case) use the event target
        e.target.classList.add('pressed');
      }else{
        //we need to find the button.
        const letter = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).toUpperCase();//get the uppercase key pressed
        const audio = document.getElementById(letter);//find the audio element with that id
        if(audio){
          const button = audio.parentNode;
          //and get it's parent
          button.classList.add('pressed');//make it pressed
        }
      }
    } 
    function mouseuphandler(e) {
      //remove the pressed class from event target
      e.target.classList.remove('pressed');
    }
    function keyuphandler(e){
      const letter = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).toUpperCase();
      const button = document.getElementById(letter).parentNode;
      button.classList.remove('pressed');
    }
    drumpad.forEach(function(el) { 
      el.addEventListener('mousedown', downhandler);
      el.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseuphandler);
      el.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseuphandler);//needed incase the mouse is released after leaving the element
    }); 
    document.addEventListener("keydown", downhandler);
    document.addEventListener("keyup", keyuphandler);
```

```css
button{
  background:#a0a0e0;
  border:1px solid #666;
  border-radius:2px;
  padding:5px;
}

button.pressed{
  background:#a0e0cb;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Drump pad</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="drumpad.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="drum-machine">
            <div id="display">
                <p id="displaytext"></p>
            </div>
                <div id="controls1">
                <button id="Heater1button"  class="drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id="Q" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>Q</button>
                <button id="Heater2button" class="drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id='W' src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>W</button>
                <button id="Heater3button" class="drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id='E' src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-3.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>E</button>
                </div>
            <div id="controls2">
                <button id="Heater4button" class="drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id='A' src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-4_1.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>A</button>
                <button id="Heater6button"  class="drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id='S'src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-6.mp3"></audio>S</button>
                <button id="OpenHHbutton"  class="drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id='D'src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Dsc_Oh.mp3"></audio>D</button>
            </div>
            <div id="controls3">
                <button id="KicknHat" class="drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id='Z'src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Kick_n_Hat.mp3"></audio>Z</button>
                <button id="Kickbutton"class="drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id='X'src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/RP4_KICK_1.mp3"></audio>X</button>
                <button id="ClosedHHbutton"class="drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id='C' src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Cev_H2.mp3"></audio>C</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

*edit*

I just noticed it's broken... hangon...

*edit*

okay now it should be good

Comment: Thank you. Man, that was really intense. Hope I never have to deal with just pure javascript in my career!

Answer (score 0):

EternalDoubter
How could I add the focus or the css class after the key event?

By creatively styling the `:active` or `:focus` pseudo classes using a box-shadow: inset ...;

Using the `:active` pseudo class:

```
button {
  background: #ededed;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:active {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px #c1c1c1;
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px #c1c1c1;
          box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px #c1c1c1;
   outline: none;
}
<button>
  Click me
</button>
```

Using the `:focus` pseudo class:

```
button {
  background: #ededed;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:focus {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px #c1c1c1;
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px #c1c1c1;
          box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px #c1c1c1;
}
<button>
  Click me
</button>
```

Comment: Sorry I realized I was not clear enough When using the `:active` pseudo class, it works, but not with the `:focus`. Nothing happens then when clicking on the button. No change of background colour.

Comment: No, i`m saying it isnt working: when I press the key that triggers the event, nothing changes. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NOOqvx